# What does the pseudo selector ":regular" do?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I've seen some code like this below:

```css
.some-element\:regular {}
```

I checked for it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) but it doesn't seem to have it listed?

So my question is, what does this pseudo selector do and what is the purpose of the backslash(`\`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a pseudo selector, CSS has special characters that cannot be applied in class names, so to use them, CSS escapes with a backslash (`\`)

here is the list of the special characters:

`!`, `"`, `#`, `$`, `%`, `&`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `*`, `+`, `,`, `-`, `.`, `/`, `:`, `;`, `<`, `=`, `>`, `?`, `@`, `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `` ` ``, `{`, `|`, `}`, and `~`

See an example:

```css
.some-element\:regular { background:red}
.some-element2:regular { background:red}
```

```html
<div class="some-element:regular"> this will be red</div>
<div class="some-element2:regular"> this will not be red</div>
```

you can see more info here about CSS special characters [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes)

Comment: Thanks....... never seen a class name written like that before so thought it was some `pseudo` selector I hadn't seen before.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a pseudo selector, looks like your class is `some-element:regular` (check your HTML file). In CSS, colons need to be escaped to be parsed as class names (and not pseudo-selectors), hence the backslash.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `:regular` [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) in CSS; the backslash there is escaping the following character, a colon.. That means that that selector is actually looking for an element with a class name of `some-element:regular`, such as:

```
<p class="some-element:regular"></p>
```